# postconf : command not found (but postfix service works)

Tags: postfix

> $ postconf -n
>
> -bash: postconf: command not found

I try to update apt-get and `--reinstall` postfix package, but no change...

How can I install postconf cmd?

Comment: How about `sudo postconf -n` then?

Comment: it works, thx... But how can I give the right to my current user for this cmd?

Comment: Two issues: (1) Your question is literally "how can I install `postconf` cmd?" but you apparently know how. You incorrectly assumed it was not installed. (2) Your comment is a separate question. For these reasons I advise you to [edit] the question and make it "how can I give the right to my current user for this cmd?" or similar (but do your research first, also against possible duplicates). If you decide to do so, then edit before there is any answer to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the command is not written in /usr/bin. It is possible that there are many other commands that do not work on your system either. This error appears more often when you have just upgraded your distribution. The fix: type logged as root or sudo

$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin

everytyhing will work "like magic" (but is not :) )

I read this answer first in an Ehsan Nazim post. For me it worked every time when I had this issue.